# Crashing while initializing direct3d.presentparameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, directx-11

I downloaded and am using the directx (dxsdk june 2010) from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812

PC is windows 7 with all the latest updates and directX 11.

The application crashes on this line:

```
Dim d3dpp As New PresentParameters()
```

A try catch gives me nothing. VS2015 itself is giving me nothing. Just using CPU and never showing the form. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput
Imports System.Windows

Public Class Form2
    Dim RunOnce As Boolean = True
    Dim gamerun As Boolean = True
    Dim bkgColor As Color = Color.Black
    Dim d3ddev As Direct3D.Device
    'Dim d3dpp As New PresentParameters

    Dim drawFont As Direct3D.Font
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim wait As Int32

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Dim d3dpp As New PresentParameters()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim strbreakpoint As String = "ASDF"
    End Try


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This code is using the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies which have been [deprecated for over a decade](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx). They only work with the .NET 1.1 or 2.0 Runtime, and do not support (officially at least) .NET 4.x. You should look at moving to a replacement like [SlimDX](https://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/).

Comment: Voted. Thanks for alternative suggestions as well.